# How to turn hard drive on again after I turn it off

Tags: linux, hardware

Just out of curiosity, I like to know if I can turn my laptop's internal hard drive on again after I've used the following command to turn it off:
`sudo udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb` 

I am looking for a way to turn the drive on again without restarting the system.

 Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try restarting through systemd... `sudo systemctl restart udisks2`

Comment: Yes, and nor it turned the drive on neither I could view the drive in `lsblk` results.

Comment: @Tower same experience here.